# Drivers are support HP 630 Notebook PC?

Tags: installation

I have 1 HP 630 Notebook PC Core i5 and want to install ubuntu
can you suggest me to install any version to be the best driver support

Answer (score 0):

I used 8.04,11.04,11.10,12.04,12.10 Versions & Now I'm using 13.04 & I found the best driver support in the last Version (13.04) & I say even its more stable than 12,04 LTS!